# view_email_url on a secured page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssl, email-studio

Is it possible to make the view_email_url link in Marketing Cloud open up on a secured page (using https protocol)?  We have purchased SSL certificates for CloudPages and images but can you apply SSL certs to the 'view email as a webpage link'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have purchased the SSL SetUp all e-mail links that have tracking information do get wrapped to https. Therefore your view as webpage link should already be https when your ssl setup of the view.yourdomain.com has been successful.

All links click.yourdomain.com, view.yourdomain.com and image.yourdomain.com and those generated links should now be in https and therefore should open on https pages.

Comment: Thank you Johannes, this answered my question.